# Facebook API in a console application

Tags: c#, facebook, visual-studio-2010

I am new to using Facebook Api and I am using it in visual studio C# , and I downloaded it's library facebook. But I want to know how to start work on it ? Should I use Windows form for it or Console is fine ? Because I just want to Update my status through Api , getting my friend list , read my statuses .
As I run this code before but It didn't show me the output

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Facebook;    

namespace Social_network_work
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var client = new FacebookClient();
            dynamic me = client.Get("totten");
        }
    }
}
```

as I am python user but now I have to use visual studio c#. `"http://csharpsdk.org/"` this link is not showing how to use it in windows 7

Comment: I don't want to use asp.net or anything else. I just want to use simple C# . Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep the command-line open so you can read the output, add the following after
the `Console.Writeline` line

```
Console.Readline();
```

Then when you run it, the output will display, and wait for you to press enter - which will allows the program to continue and exit/quit.

Also, in short, yes you should be able to create the app as a complete command-line application without issue.

Comment: can I also get my own friend list using this in command-line application , actually I want to extract data.

Answer (score 2):

Your question doesn't have much to do with Windows 7.

You sample works fine. You just don't have any line writting to the console.
Try :

```
var client = new FacebookClient();
var me = client.Get("totten");

Console.WriteLine(me);
```

Comment: bro it still not giving me the output mean output display for a while and than cmd screen gone

Comment: I don't want to use asp.net or anything else. I just want to use simple C# . Is it possible ?

Comment: I have the same problem I don't know how to use it in Visual studio and how to integrate it . I just install all the libraries but it didn't show me the result in console and not working in Windows Form.